Simple explanation for why execlp() uses argv[1] twice in a row?
Can you explain why we have to give argv[1] twice?
When I change the code to only one argv[1] the console executes the program ./a.out echo first hello cool and I do not see the echo. I just see that it had been executed three times. I read the man pages, but it is a little bit foggy to understand. thanks
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){
    
    for (int i=2; i<argc; i+=1){
        pid_t p = fork();
        if (p== -1){
            perror ("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (p==0){
            execlp(argv[1], argv[1], argv[i], NULL); //why argv[1] twice
            perror("exec");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        else{
            int stat;
            pid_t x = wait(&stat);

            if (x==-1){
                perror("wait");
                continue;
            }
            if(WIFEXITED(stat)){
                printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(stat));
            }
        }
        
    }

}




The first argument is the name of the executable that is executed.  The 2nd argument is the value that is passed as argv[0] to the process.  Play around with it.  Instead of calling echo, call your own program that prints out its arguments.

When reading arguments, argv[0] is traditionally the name of the program being executed.  Most (if not all) shells will call programs in this way.
Because of this, programs typically expect arguments passed to it to start with argv[1].
The above is not a hard requirement however.  The first argument can be anything, and in fact argc can be zero:
Can argc be zero on a POSIX system?

And I think the login shell is provided - for argv[0]

@ikegami: traditionally, a dash is added before the basename of argv[0] to indicate a login shell.  Bash and other modern shells take an argument (-l for Bash) to indicate that it should be a login shell.

Here's a program that deliberately allows you to fake the argv[0] of the command you execute — I call it fakir, compiled from fakir.c:
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void err_sysrem(const char *fmt, ...);
static void err_usage(const char *usestr);
static void err_setarg0(const char *argv0);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc < 3)
        err_usage("command fake-name [arg ...]");
    execv(argv[1], &argv[2]);
    err_sysrem("Failed to execute %s\n", argv[1]);
    return 127;
}

static const char *arg0 = "-undefined-";

static void err_setarg0(const char *argv0)
{
    arg0 = argv0;
}

static void err_usage(const char *usestr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s %s\n", arg0, usestr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void err_sysrem(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", arg0);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errno != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s", errno, strerror(errno));
    putc('\n', stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

Examples of use:
$ fakir
Usage: fakir command fake-name [arg ...]
$ fakir ps xyz 
fakir: Failed to execute ps
2: No such file or directory
$ fakir xyz obsidian 
fakir: Failed to execute xyz
13: Permission denied
$ fakir /bin/ps orange-headed-borer-weevil -t ttys003
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 2488 ttys003    0:00.01 login -pf jonathanleffler
 2499 ttys003    0:00.68 -zsh
16758 ttys003    0:00.01 orange-headed-borer-weevil -t ttys003
$ fakir /bin/ps ozymandias -f -t ttys003                
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0  2488  2393   0 13May24 ttys003    0:00.01 login -pf jonathanleffler
  502  2499  2488   0 13May24 ttys003    0:00.68 -zsh
    0 16759  2499   0  3:06PM ttys003    0:00.01 ozymandias -f -t ttys003
$

The err_*() functions are minimalist implementations of a full set of error reporting functions available in my SOQ (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files stderr.c and stderr.h in the src/libsoq sub-directory.  They are similar to the err(3)
functions available on Linux.
The code could use execvp() instead of execv().  However, because they lack flexibility, I hardly ever use the execl() and execlp() functions.  When I do use them, it is because the lack of flexibility is exactly what's desired.
